# Limit traffic from single IP behind Linux router

Tags: linux, bandwidth, rate-limits

I have a router running Ubuntu Linux. It has two network interfaces: `p3p1` for WAN, and `br0` for LAN (this is a bridge). On the LAN there is a PC with ip `192.168.3.7`.

How do I limit all traffic coming from `192.168.3.7` and destined for the WAN, to 100kbps?

Comment: Maybe you can find something interesting in this [link](https://www.linux.com/learn/docs/ldp/440-Bandwidth-Limiting-HOWTO) and in [this one](http://lartc.org/lartc.pdf).

Comment: One question is, does this user have a static IP? If you block them by IP, but if their IP changes via DHCP your method will no longer work. You may want to look into a way of trying to limit them by MAC address.

Comment: The IP is static; I set it in the dhcp server's configuration file, from the MAC address.